# Android studio - share data between activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im making an app/game in android studio. And I have over 10 activities in my app/game and I have f.eks "int HP" I want to share with the others activities.

Comment: some more code would be helpful

Comment: Question is not clear. add more about problem

Comment: Take a look at the Intent class.

Comment: You can use shared preference to share your data.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138389/using-shared-preferences-in-between-activities

Answer (score 1):

Follwing way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class)
intent.putExtra("message", message);
startActivity(intent);
```

for more understanding go through this link

http://javatechig.com/android/pass-a-data-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android