# Unable to Get Push Value in android

Tags: android

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {


        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("payload");
        String newspushid1= intent.getStringExtra("payload1");
        gc.setnews_pushid(newspushid1);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        BackgroundAlert bg = new BackgroundAlert(mNotificationManager, msg);
        bg.onReceive(getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }
```

In this i am Getting value of msg and Push id (helloworld  and  101 respectively) i want get this value in another activity .

```
if (gdata.getPush_message() != null) {

            String push_id_value = gdata.getnews_pushid();

            Log.e("CATID", "ID-->" + push_id_value);
}
```

I have apply this code for getting value .from GCMIntentService class but i am getting same value push_id_value ,getPush_message in another activity which is hello world i am unable to get value 101 in another activity please check my code tell me solution .

Comment: here what is `gdata` ?

Comment: its is object of seter and geter class

Comment: oh fine then where you set that value?

Comment: gc.setnews_pushid(newspushid1);   this is set and this get gdata.getnews_pushid();

Comment: ok fine and the final question Where you crate `gc` object? like :`POJO pj=new POJO();`

Comment: yes actually i want to set both payload seperatly and get seperatly in another activity ?

Comment: that's the main issue. you can't do this with different context.better to used on constant class as static variable or save into preferences

Comment: can u please Provide me code for that plz ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Constant` Class like :

```
 public class Constant {    
 public static String PAYLOAD = "";
 public static String PAYLOAD_1 = "";
}
```

Now, you can set this value in `Activity1` like

```
Constant.PAYLOAD = intent.getStringExtra("payload");
Constant.PAYLOAD_1= intent.getStringExtra("payload1");
```

Now, get this value in `Activity2` like:

```
 String push_id_value = Constant.PAYLOAD;
 String push_id_value1 = Constant.PAYLOAD_1;
```

And/or for **Preference** go to my this answer:[Android. How to save user name and password after the app is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697172/android-how-to-save-user-name-and-password-after-the-app-is-closed/21697274#21697274)

Comment: please add me i sent u friend request

Comment: my email id is anilat87@gmail.com plz add me

Answer (score 1):

In your current Activity,

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
}
```

Use this technique to pass values from one Activity to another.

Comment: Getting nUll value see i am Pusing value from Server

Comment: @AB you're right on way. +1 up here problem some where else.