# Saving variables on android til the app closes

Tags: java, android

I have a basic understanding of java and android but am still new and am struggling to find the correct way to save a variable and be able to access it/read it from other classes/activities. I have seen singletons but I am confused if it is the right way and how it would look, also do I need to make sure its thread safe?

Is there a better way that I am unaware of?

Basically I have a login that gets a username and some info about that user. How can I save that to a class/singleton and access it later?

**EDIT**

after some more searching I found this example:

```
public class Drivers {

      private static Array drivers;


          public static void setDrivers(Array c){
                drivers = c;
            }


           public static Array getDrivers(){
                return drivers;
            }


}
```

and get and set like this:

```
public class AnyClass {
{
    int clicks = ActionClass.getDrivers();
    ActionClass.setDrivers(0);
}
```

Would this work/be correct?

Comment: I have a better idea you can saved this variable into one constant class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `Constant` Class like :

```
public class Constant {    
public static String USERNAME = "";
public static String PASSWORD = "";
```

}

Now, you can set this value in `Activity1` like

```
Constant.USERNAME = "uname";
Constant.PASSWORD= "password";
```

Now, get this value in `Activity2` like:

```
String u_name = Constant.USERNAME;
String pass = Constant.PASSWORD;
```

You can access this variables any where in your app.

And/or for **Preference** go to my this answer:[Android. How to save user name and password after the app is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697172/android-how-to-save-user-name-and-password-after-the-app-is-closed/21697274#21697274)

Comment: Do I just create a normal new java class, or is a Constant  Class something different?

Comment: @BluGeni yes anywhere in your package

Comment: This was so much easier than I was making it out to be, thank you so much for the simple answer that works perfectly how I needed

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`SharedPreferences`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) (kind of a persistence layer). Or you could pass data through [`Intent`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android).

Comment: SharedPreferences holds the values even after the app closes correct? and with an Intent I would have to pass the variables from every activity to keep track of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit(); 
 editor.putString("PASSWORD_KEY", mPassword);
 editor.commit();

 String s = sharedPreferences.getString("PASSWORD_KEY", ""); // get the saved string
```